# The role of the rewiring probability in small world networks

Tags: graph-theory, network

I am generating some network samples by using small-world package provided by `igraph` in `R`. When I keep the number of nodes and the neighborhood parameter the same, the number of edges do not change when changing the rewiring  probability. I was wondering if someone could explain me the exact role of this parameter. For instance, what does exactly happen if I constantly increase the rewiring  probability? It is obvious that the density of the graph does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small-world networks start out with nodes that can be visualized as lying on a circle in the plane. Each node is initially connected to some number $k$ of nearest neighbors. Then each edge is considered for re-wiring.  With some probability (the re-wiring probability) each edge is disconnected from one of its ends and then connected to a random node in the network instead. These “long-distance” edges give the network its small-world behavior (short paths between arbitrary nodes).

The details can be found in a [famous paper](http://www.nature.com/articles/30918) by Watts and Strogatz or [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watts%E2%80%93Strogatz_model?wprov=sfti1).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. When I start increasing the re-wiring probability, what feature exactly changes in the network? For example, what is the difference between having $p=0.01$ and $p=0.99$?

Comment: Think of it this way: When $p=0$, you have a highly structured network with only local or “short-distance” edges. (Technically I think it is called a ring lattice.) When $p=1$ you have an Erdos-Renyi random network, where nearly all of the edges are nonlocal or “long-distance.”  The main point of the original paper is that most of the important nonlocal behavior, such as short paths between randomly selected nodes, emerges even for very small values of $p$.